# simple boot sector coding: Filling the 512 Byte with 0

Tags: x86, nasm, boot

I use the Bochs simulator to run a boot sector, which coded in NASM like this:

```
  org 07c00h                  ;told the compiler to load the code to 0x7c00h
  mov ax, cs                 
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  call    DispStr             ;call the string process 
  jmp $                       ;infinite loop
 DispStr:
   mov ax, BootMessage        
   mov bp, ax                 ;ES:BP = string address    
   mov cx, 16                 ;CX = length of the string
   mov ax, 01301h             ;AH = 13, AL = 01H
   mov bx, 000ch              ;(BH = 0) 
   mov dl, 0                  
   int 10h                    ;10h interrupt
   ret
 BootMessage:    db  "Hello, OS world!"  ;message printed
 times    510-($-$$)  db  0              ;fill the left of the 510 byte with 0 
 dw  0xaa55
```

If `times    510-($-$$)  db  0` if forbidden, is there any alternative way to fill the left of 510 byte area with 0?

I've tried loop command, but can not work properly.

Comment: _"If times    510-($-$$)  db  0 if forbidden"_ Why would it be forbidden?

Comment: @Michael But the assistant of our OS class asked us to come up with an optional way to fill the blank...

Comment: Huh. Sounds like a waste of time to me. Is this an OS class or a NASM directives class?

Comment: an OS class with experiments using NASM

Comment: The TA is wasting your time. There are far more important things in an OS dev class than how to use rep vs $-$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way would be to use a preprocessor loop (`%rep`):

```
%rep 510-($-$$)
db 0
%endrep
```

If your TA still isn't satisfied I'll leave it to you to dig through the NASM manual for other possible ways of achieving the same thing.